# .bat that works ok if manually but triggers if from Windows Task Manager

Tags: batch-file

I have the below .bat that works good if I manually execute it but if Windows Task Manager executes in the same conditions, it triggers the calc.exe, which is wrong.

Any ideas why?

```
@ECHO OFF
:B
tasklist | find "1.exe" > C:\Users\1.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in (1.txt) do (
set num=%%a
set num=!num:.=!
)
if !num! leq 150000 (goto :startscripts)
GOTO Exit 
:StartScripts
start calc.exe 
:Exit
```

**this is the 1.txt:**

1.exe              4588 Console                    2    191,160 K

Comment: I'd suggest you use the full path to `1.txt` in the `For` parentheses too. When run in the Task Scheduler, it is likely that the current directory is not that which you're expecting. The string `191,160` cannot be compared as a number you need to get rid of the comma.

Comment: The output example shows a comma for the thousand separator but the code shows you removing a period from the number.  Also, instead of creating a file of the tasklist output, just parse the command in a `FOR /F` command.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could simplify your code by not writing out a file at all.  Just parse the output of the command.

```
@ECHO OFF
set "num="
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "1.exe"') do set num=%%a
IF DEFINED num if %num:,=% leq 150000 start calc.exe
```

Comment: Hi There,Thanks for the quick reply. Tried your code but i'm getting the below error: 150000 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @cokestone, what is the value of `num` before the `IF` commands?

Comment: Worked! Thanks!